# Regex that doesn't work with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Sorry if title is not descriptive enough, but I really don't know how to summarize it and any suggestions are welcome. I wrote a useful piece of regex for matching lines in sql files, that are inserting data to specific tables (that contains cache). It goes like this:

```
(--\s--\sDumping\sdata\sfor\stable\s`(cache_\w+|cache)`.*?)(?=(--\n--.+Table\sstructure\sfor\stable\s`.+`.*--))
```

So now when I have file like this:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `cache_content`
--

something

--
-- Dumping data for table `cache_content`
--

INSERT INTO `cache_content` etc.


--
-- Table structure for table `cache`
--

something

--
-- Dumping data for table `cache`
--

INSERT INTO `cache` etc.


--
-- Table structure for table `notcache`
--

something

--
-- Dumping data for table `notcache`
--
```

It matches all inserts to those tables, and I would like to remove them (as those are tables with cache) by using `sed` , and specifically I wrote a simple bash script for doing this:

```
REGEX="(--\s--\sDumping\sdata\sfor\stable\s\`(cache_\w+|cache)\`.*?)(?=(--\n--.+Table\sstructure\sfor\stable\s\`.+\`.*--))"
sed -i "s/${REGEX}//g" $1
```

Now the problem is that it works in my regex tester, but it doesn't work at all with `sed`. `sed` just doesn't changing file at all, and I'm buffled. I read somewhere that `sed` is line based but could this be the problem, or something else?

Added #1:
If it is impossible to accomplish with `sed` what would be the good alternative? Is anything sed-like that would do it?

Comment: The fact that `sed` is line based is one of your problems, it is also probably going to have a hard time with `\s` and `\w` in your regex.  You may want to consider using Perl or some other scripting language instead of bash/sed.

Comment: You're also using lookaheads, which sed doesn't support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use `sed` as it's line-oriented and your pattern has to match across multiple lines.  (You could break your pattern up into a start pattern and an end pattern and try `/start_pattern/,/end_pattern/p`, but then you'd need separate `start_pattern`s for each of your tables, because a line range in `sed` can only match once in the input.)

You should able to take a simplified start pattern/end pattern approach in `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { x = 1 }; /^-- Dumping data for table `cache(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?`$/ { x = 0 }; /^-- Table structure for table `[^`]+`$/{ x = 1 }; (x == 1) { print }' $1
```

Or you could still take your one-ginormous-regexp-over-the-entire-file approach (with some minor modifications) in a "real" scripting language:

```
ruby -e 'File.write(ARGV[0],File.read(ARGV[0]).gsub(/(--\s--\sDumping\sdata\sfor\stable\s`(?:cache_\w+|cache)`.*?)(?=(?:--\n--\s+Table\sstructure\sfor\stable\s`[^`]+`\s*\n--))/m,""))' $1
```

Comment: This Ruby code matches strings just fine, but how to remove the match from file, in place? Could you add this please? Unfortunately I don't know Ruby, and that piece of code could be useful for someone else also.

Comment: Edited so that the Ruby example now edits the file in place.  (Also, both examples now delete the cache table contents instead of keeping them and deleting everything else!)

Comment: This is a very handy snippet for multiline regex replacing in place :) . And it encouraged me to learn Ruby or Python on top of bash. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Why create additional work if you can avoid it in the first place? :)

Simply don't generate the statements for tables you're not interested in. For example if you're using MySQL:

```
mysqldump --ignore-table=<...> --ignore-table=<...>
```

Other databases will have a similar option.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but this is not for my dumps :) . Sometimes someone can send me his database dumped the default way, and then that kind of script would be handy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sed, try using perl:

```
perl -e 'undef $/; $_ = <>; s/YOUR_REGEX_HERE//gs; print' $1
```

Comment: Isn't -p executing regex per-line, so it would be useless in my case? I would love if it would work.

Comment: You're right, my bad, thanks. I've corrected the answer, see above.

Answer (score 0):

start your sed by keeping everything in buffer so

```
sed "H
$ {
  x
#  your code here
  }
```

1. H load each line into the buffer
2. when last line( $) occur
3. Swap current line with the buffer (so all the file is in your work area)
4. Your code work on all the line.

Be careefful, ^ and $ are the first and last char of the file, no more of the line wich are separated by \n